# Reassigning values in Map

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists. Minimal example:

```
lists = {{a,b,c},{d,e,f}}
```

I want to set the values on position 2 (b and e) to the value of their right neighbour (c and f). I'm sure there must be a solution with Map, similar to this:

```
Map[#[[2]] = #[[3]] &, lists]
```

How can I make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Alternative way: `lists.ReplacePart[
  IdentityMatrix[Length[First@lists]], {{2, 2} -> 0, {3, 2} -> 1}]`

Comment: Direct assignment seems simplest for this. `lists[[All, 2]] = lists[[All, 3]]`

Comment: @Edmund. Good solution, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a rundown of some methods:

```
Map[ReplacePart[#, 2 -> #[[3]]] &, lists]
lists[[All, 2]] = lists[[All, 3]] (* Changes `lists` *)
lists /. {a_, _, b_} :> {a, b, b}
lists[[All, {1, 3, 3}]]
MapThread[{#, #3, #3} &, Transpose[lists]]
{#, #3, #3} & @@@ lists
```

A rather exotic way of addressing a particular part of an expression:

```
lists = {
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
   {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17}
   };
lists /. {s : Repeated[_, {3}], a_, b_, r___} :> {s, a, a, r}
```

> `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 14, 16, 17}}`

Of course, all these versions are not equals. The ones relying on pattern matching should be the slowest ones, `Part` (`[[ ]]`) should be fast, and so should anonymous functions paired with basic operators (e.g. `{#, #3, #3} & @@@ lists`.)

Comment: I tried the first ("ReplacePart[...]") solution, which was fine. But I liked the direkt assignment (solution #2) most. However, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to swap positions 2 and 3, or just duplicate position 3?

For the first,

```
#[[{1, 3, 2}]] & /@ lists
```

returns

```
(*{{a, c, b}, {d, f, e}}*)
```

For the second,

```
#[[{1, 3, 3}]] & /@ lists
```

returns

```
(* {{a, c, c}, {d, f, f}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very wrong way to do it, but hopefully it might provide insight. First of all, your approach with slightly corrected syntax:

```
lists = {{a,b,c},{d,e,f}}
Map[(#[[2]] = #[[3]]) &, lists]
```

The `Set (=)` operation has the attribute `HoldFirst`, therefore it attemps to set the entire `{a, b, c}[[2]]` construct to `c`. That doesn't make any sense, so it returns the output of `Set` (which is the right hands side of the expression) and does nothing else.

Now if we try to override that with an `Evaluate`:

```
Map[(Evaluate[#[[2]]] = #[[3]]) &, lists]
```

then #[[2]] evaluates all the way to `b` and `b` gets set to `c`. This relies on `b` not having a value prior to the assignment. Otherwise we would get some error such as "could not assign `c` to raw object `5`".

Bear in mind, that this approach does not change the definition of `lists`. `lists` is still `{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}`, but after the `Map` command, `b` gets an `OwnValue` of `c` and `e` - of `f`. So in almost every expression using `lists` it would evaluate all the way to `{{a, c, c}, {d, f, f}}`. But as soon as you type `b=5; e=6`, the output of lists will become `{{a, 5, c}, {d, 6, f}}`.

**TL;DR** almost certainly, unless you are actually wanting to do a bulk assignment of values to symbols, you should use the solutions in the other answers.

Comment: This was actually helpful, didn't know many of these things. Thanks!